# Stored procedure execution from Cloud Datafusion

Tags: google-bigquery, google-groups, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I am trying to execute stored procedure which is present bigquery using Datafusion Bigquery Execute i.e, am calling the procedure from Big query execute SQL command .The pipeline is failing with Null exception.Is that the Bigquery execute only to run SQL commands not for calling procedures or Functions .

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Bigquery stored procedures use different calling signature as explained here
https://www.google.com/amp/s/cloudblog.withgoogle.com/products/data-analytics/command-and-control-now-easier-in-bigquery-with-scripting-and-stored-procedures/amp/

Note that it is a feature still in beta and may change going forward.
One thing I found following that example is over jdbc I had to execute all the statements as a Bloc rather than one by one

```
DECLARE target_employee_id INT64 DEFAULT 9;
DECLARE employee_hierarchy ARRAY<INT64>;
CALL dataset.GetEmployeeHierarchy(target_employee_id, employee_hierarchy)
SELECT target_employee, employee_hierarchy;
```

Comment: I have declared a procedure with no parameters in Bigquery and trying to call the same procedure using Cloud Datafusion Bigquery execute component SQL command.Code:create or replace procedure proc_name Begin update table set empid=40  end;..Then calling using call proc_name.I am able to execute these statements in Bigquery tool.But when calling the same call statement from Datafusion it is failing with Null exception.Can anyone please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: I think it is actually performing the update, just the driver is looking for a result set that isn't there. Try adding a dummy select statement after the call statement to confirm

Comment: Am able to execute the procedure from Datafusion  by adding project name.datasetname.tablename in call statement .Thank you for the help .